# Why the principle of explosion works?

Tags: logic

I was reading about the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) and there is one thing I don't get.

Based on my understanding, the principle of explosion goes as follows: Given two statements $P$ and $Q$, and suppose $P$ and $\neg P$ are both true. Then we assert that $P\lor Q$ is true since $P$ is true. Finally, since $\neg P$ is true, it follows that $Q$ must be true for $P\lor Q$ to be true.

How does this form of deduction make sense? What I don't get is that if both $P$ and $\neg P$ are true, then it is a contradiction. At this point, we cannot conclude whether $P$ is true or false. So, it would be meaningless to determine whether $P\lor Q$ is true.

Comment: The point is from a contradiction you can deduce any $Q$ in your formal proof system.

Comment: If $P$ and $\lnot P$ *have* both been derived at a point, then you can conclude that $P$ is true - because, you *have* done so.  Also that it is false; simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to see why the principle of explosion "should" be true. Here's one which I think should be particularly approachable (even if it's ultimately not "the right way" to see why explosion should be true):

Surely you agree that from $P$ and $\lnot P$ we can derive false, $\bot$. But now for *any statement $Q$ at all*, $\bot \to Q$ is a tautology. If you like, this is because

$$\bot \to Q \equiv \lnot \bot \lor q \equiv \top \lor q \equiv \top$$

So if we have $P$ and $\lnot P$ we can get $\bot$, and from $\bot$ we can get any $Q$ we like.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by getting $\bot$ from $P$ and $\neg P$? Contradiction implies $P$ is false?

Comment: You can think of $\lnot P$ as an abbreviation for $P \to \bot$. So from $P$ and $P \to \bot$ we can derive $\bot$.

Comment: I don't understand the point of deriving $\bot$...

Comment: The point is that, for any $Q$, $\bot \to Q \equiv \top$ (by the proof I gave in the body of the answer). So as soon as we've derived $\bot$, we know that we can derive any $Q$ we want!